# Using Akubra-HDFS with Cloudera CDH4

Tags: hadoop, storage, hdfs, cloudera, fedora-commons

I am experimenting with using [Akubra-HDFS](http://wiki.opf-labs.org/display/SP/akubra-hdfs) as the low level storage for the [fedora commons](http://fedora-commons.org/) server. I followed the procedure similar to [installation of IRODS](https://www.irods.org/index.php/Fedora) to setup Akubra-HDFS. The fedora server worked with Hadoop (version 1.0.4) as its storage.  But, I had trouble using the Akubra-HDFS library with either Cloudera CDH4 / Apache Hadoop 2.0.3alpha - the High Availability (HA) distributions. I wanted to share my findings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As AKubra-HDFS is a new experimental library there is not much resources about it in the internet. I had to figure out the solution by experimenting out with different dependency jars.

Follow the instructions at https://github.com/fasseg/akubra-hdfs

Instead of the jars listed there for Hadoop 1.x.x, Copy the below jar files from CDH4 (installation folder) to the fedora lib folder.

1. commons-cli-1.2.jar
2. commons-configuration-1.6.jar
3. commons-lang-2.4.jar
4. - google-collections-1.0-rc2.jar (This has to removed from the fedora lib folder).
5. guava-11.0.2.jar (This is a newer version of google-collections)
6. hadoop-auth-2.0.0-cdh4.1.3.jar
7. hadoop-common-2.0.0-cdh4.1.3.jar
8. hadoop-hdfs-2.0.0-cdh4.1.3.jar
9. protobuf-java-2.4.0a.jar